# Drag and Drop not working in Chrome Driver Version 76.0.3809.100

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Drag and Drop is not working in chrome driver version 76.0.3809.100.
I have tried out several code blocks for achieving this,but the code runs without any issues but no action is happening.

Selenium and Chrome Driver versions are given below:
Selenium.Webdriver: v3.141.0
Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver: v76.0.3809.68

Please find the code block that i used to achieve drag and dop

```
IAction dragAndDrop1 = builder1.ClickAndHold(source).MoveToElement(destination).Release(destination).Build();
dragAndDrop1.Perform();
```

I also tried the following code block

```
Actions ac= new Actions(driver);
ac.DragAndDrop(source, destination).Build().Perform();
```